# I have a json file where I am setting variables and I have CSV file to read value from it .How can I use intuit Karate to do it easily?

Tags: karate

I have json file as below.

```
   {
book : {bookId : '<bookId>' , 
         bookName : '<bookName>'
         },
staff : {
     sfattid : '<sfattid>',
     name : '<name>'
     },
libraryMember : { 
libMembId : '<libMembId>',
name : '<libraryMember>'

         }
}
```

I have below CVS 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXZoM.png)

The CSV file which have headers as the above variable in json file .I want to use CSV file in scenario outline table and set values for the JSON file .Can you please suggest some code which automatic reads the json set the corresponding value for each row .

I was thinking below code should work but it is not working

Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic table
    from a csv file

```
Scenario Outline: staffname name: <name>
    * text jsonPayLoad = call read('readJson.feature')
    Given url 'http://localhost:8089/'
    And path 'returnBook'
    And request jsonPayLoad
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Then match karate.jsonPath(response,"$.status") ==  '<status>' 
    Examples:
    | read('bookreturn.csv') |
```

Comment: voting to close as unclear. please try to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Peter,I have updated the question .Could you please have a look again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `read('bookreturn.csv')` should be an **Array** of **JSON** objects.

For example in this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

Make this change:

```
Background:
    * def kittens = [{name: 'Billie'}, {name: 'Wild'}]
```

Comment: I have added below line to code and it is working  " * def jsonPayLoad = read('readJson.feature')"  the only issue is with numbers .When i ma trying to pass bookid or staffid as number it is not filling the value for the variable .could you suggest something ?

Comment: @BikashAgrawala don't use the single quotes for numbers. try again.

Comment: HI Peter-below code is working Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic table
    from a csv file

Scenario Outline: staffname name: <name>
   When json payload =  {book : {bookId : '<bookId>' , bookName : '<bookName>',},staff : {sfattid : '<sfattid>', name : '<name>'},libraryMember : { libMembId : '<libMembId>' ,name : '<libraryMember>'}}
    Given url 'http://localhost:8089/'
    And path 'returnBook'
    And request payload
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Then match karate.jsonPath(response,"$.status") ==  '<status>' 

    Examples:
    | read('bookreturn.csv') |